# No parameters in cursor SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with creating a cursor for a school project. I want to give people suggestions based on their favorites.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PrintSongsByGenre] 
AS
    DECLARE @UserID AS INT;
    DECLARE @Genre AS VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @GenreCursor AS CURSOR;

    SET @GenreCursor = CURSOR FOR
        SELECT MAX(s.genre) 
        FROM Song s
        LEFT JOIN Favorite_Song fs on s.song_ID = fs.song_ID
        WHERE fs.user_ID = @UserID;

    OPEN @GenreCursor;

    DELETE FROM Suggestions 
    WHERE userID = @UserID;

    FETCH NEXT FROM @GenreCursor INTO @Genre;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Suggestions ([userId], genre)
        VALUES (@UserID, @Genre)
    END;

    CLOSE @GenreCursor;
    DEALLOCATE @GenreCursor;
```

I have created the above and it has worked on a older version of SQL Server but it doesn't work anymore. The stored procedure doesn't have parameters anymore.

Now I don't know how to recreate these parameters.

Comment: Why are you even using a ***cursor*** for this?!?!?! Could be **easily** done in a much nicer, **set-based** fashion in a single `INSERT INTO :...` statement.....

Comment: Haha i know its stupid. But we need to make a cursor for school exam in our project.

Comment: Found already a solution